# Prefetch exception when using an array of structures

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I'm using an array of structures and the definition looks something like this:

```
typedef struct testcase {
    init_testcase       init_tc_fn;
    close_tc_fn_t       close_tc_fn;
    run_tc_fn_t     run_tc_fn;
    get_result_tc_fn_t  get_result_tc_fn;
    isr_testcase        isr_fn;
}tc;
```

The declaration of the structure variable looks something like this:

```
tc tc_tbl[] = {{Ainit, Aclose, Arun, Aresult, 0},{Binit, Bclose, Brun, Bresult, 0}....etc}
```

etc... = upto 94 entries (test cases). Based upon a switch-case user response, I'm returning the function to be executed.

Now, this approach has worked well up until the 94th entry. I added new entries and when I try to access the 95th entry, I get an Exception: Prefetch at address <0xaddress>.

The code compiles just fine and this happens when I run the code and try to access the 95th entry. Is there a limit on the number of entries I can have?

Comment: Ok, so it was a very fundamental error on my part.
For some test cases, I use the same functions with conditional flow.
I forgot to include an array element for each test case irrespective of whether it is a standalone test case or more than one test case is bundled together.

Because of this I was overshooting the structure array when accessing the newer test cases. I hope this makes sense.